# javascript - function.prototype.XXX , can I understand it as OOP Class static property/member XXX?

Tags: javascript

```
    var seven;
    var new_seven;
    var new_seven_1;
    seven = function () {
          this.a = 7;
          };
    new_seven = new seven();
    new_seven_1=new seven();      
    console.log(seven.prototype.a + "\t" + new_seven.a + "\t" + new_seven_1.a);
    seven.prototype.a = 49;
    console.log(seven.prototype.a + "\t" + new_seven.a + "\t" + new_seven_1.a);
    new_seven.a = 14;
    console.log(seven.prototype.a + "\t" + new_seven.a + "\t" + new_seven_1.a);
    new_seven_1.a=71;
    console.log(seven.prototype.a + "\t" + new_seven.a + "\t" + new_seven_1.a);
```

I have test the above script on Chrome, it output:

```
 undefined  7   7
 49 7   7
 49 14  7
 49 14  71
```

I am a newbie to javascript, and like to understand what is happening
*Can I understand the above code as this:*

```
seven.prototype.??? <== access to Class static properties  
new_seven.??? / new_seven_1.???  // <== access to Class instance(Object) properties
```

I have view the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) but I cannot found my question answered.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've more or less got it. You can think of prototype as attaching properties to the template for the object instead of to the instance.

Object.prototype is mostly used to attach member methods to the JavaScript equivalent of a class.

You could define member functions in the "constructor" of the class, the same way you define member properties, but that has a performance drawback since each object instantiated from the class would get its own copy of the method definition. By instead attaching the methods to the prototype, the object instances don't need to carry around those duplicate method definitions, so the objects consume less memory.

```
var seven = function () { // in OOP terms, think of this as a constructor
    this.a = 7; // the "a" property of the object is set equal to 7 when a new object is created
};
var new_seven = new seven(); // this runs the constructor, so "a" = 7    
seven.prototype.a = 49;// this attaches an "a" property on the prototype or shared template 
                       // for the seven object, but since seven's constructor overrides 
                       // the "a" value, this won't actually do anything. 
new_seven.a = 14; // this sets the instance's value to 14
```

Answer (score 0):

seven.prototype.??? //adds another property to the function object. So that when you create another object say new_seven for instance, you are turning `new_seven` into an object and then with the use of `new` keyword in conjunction with the function `seven()`, new_seven inherits or gets it's own copy of the function `seven()`'s properties plus all the prototype variables.

say for instance in this block of code.

```
//constructor for car object
var car = function(){
    this.brand = "";
}
//But then you wanted it to have more properties so you use .prototype
car.prototype.price = "$100"; 
//you are adding another property for the constructor car() which is price
//with the default value of $100

//then you decide to create a new car
var somecar = new car(); //somecar inherits a brand new properties of car()
somecar.brand = "Porsche";// you decide what brand somecar is without affecting the properties of the constructor car()
somecar.price = "$100,000"; //with the help of prototype, the constructor car() had a new property which is price and can now be inherited by new objects. 
//you then change the default price from which is $100 to $100,1000, but this doesn't affect the car() constructor which is neat.

//You may now access the somecar's properties note: that these properties can be dynamically changed.
console.log("brand : "+somecar.brand+" , price :"+somecar.price);
```

hope this helps.